# How to get return codes from PGP Command Line code

Tags: command-line, powerbuilder, pgp

I am using a McAfee E-Business Server v8.6 and I wanted to get the return codes from the encryption/decryption commands from the command line. I run the said codes from PowerBuilder. I wanted to get the return codes from the log file set in the configuration. Would somebody know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about PGP in particular, but if these are being run locally, this is how I run an external command and get the return code:

**ExternalFunctionPrototypes**

```
FUNCTION boolean CreateProcess(string AppName, string CommLine, long l1, long l2, boolean binh, long creationflags, long l3, string dir, str_startupinfo startupinfo, ref str_processinformation pi ) library 'kernel32.dll' alias for "CreateProcessW"
FUNCTION long WaitForSingleObject ( ulong ul_Notification, long lmillisecs ) library "kernel32.dll"
FUNCTION long GetExitCodeProcess(ulong hProcess,ref ulong lpExitCode) LIBRARY "kernel32.dll"
FUNCTION boolean CloseHandle(ulong h) library 'kernel32.dll'
```

**function of_runandwait (string as_command, boolean ab_Visible) returns ulong**

```
constant long STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1
constant long CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 16
constant long NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 32
constant long INFINITE = -1
boolean lb_Return
long ll_Null, ll_CreationFlags, ll_Return
ulong lul_ProcessReturn
string ls_CurDir, ls_Null
str_StartupInfo lstr_Start
str_Processinformation lstr_PI

SetNull(ll_Null)
SetNull(ls_Null)
SetNull(ls_CurDir)

lstr_Start.cb                = 72
lstr_Start.dwFlags       = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
IF ab_Visible THEN
    lstr_Start.wShowWindow   = 1
ELSE
    lstr_Start.wShowWindow   = 0
END IF

ll_CreationFlags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS

lb_Return = CreateProcess (ls_Null, as_Command, ll_Null, ll_Null, FALSE, ll_CreationFlags, ll_Null, ls_CurDir, lstr_Start, lstr_PI)
ll_Return = WaitForSingleObject (lstr_PI.hProcess, INFINITE)
ll_Return = GetExitCodeProcess (lstr_PI.hProcess, lul_ProcessReturn)
CloseHandle(lstr_PI.hProcess)
CloseHandle(lstr_PI.hThread)

RETURN lul_ProcessReturn
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck,

Terry.